# Using the Alexa-SDK how can I get this.emit() method to return multiple objects in a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, function

I'm trying to get multiple account id's from a JSON array using the emit() method.  The emit method is defined from the Alexa-SDK.  The problem is that its emitting only one of the values and not all.  How can I get the emit()method to return both object values in a JSON array?

Here is my code snippet:

```
'use strict';

const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');

const handlers = {
  'LaunchRequest': function() {
    this.emit(':tell', 'sure');
    this.emit('getEmployeeInfoIntent');
  },
  'getEmployeeInfoIntent': function() {
    var empinfoData = {
    "employees": [{
        "account_id": 8675309
      },{
        "account_id": 54321
      }]
    };
    for (var i in empinfoData) {
      var employeeInfo = empinfoData[i].account_id;
      this.emit(':tell', 'The accounts available are id number' + employeeInfo);
      //return only 8675309 but I want 8675309 and 54321
    };
  }
}; ///end of handler

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
  alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
  alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
  alexa.execute();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var objtwo = {
  "employees": [{
    "account_id": 8675309
  },{
    "account_id": 54321
  }]
}

// mythis variable is defined globally
var mythis = this;

function getJSONArray() {
  //var reqresponse = this.responseText;
  //var objtwo = JSON.parse(reqresponse); 
  var empinfoData = objtwo.employees;
  var allIds = [];
  for (var i of empinfoData) {
    var employeeInfo = i["account_id"];
    allIds.push(employeeInfo);
  };
  return allIds;
};
console.log(getJSONArray());
```

Save the emploeeInfo's into an Array and emit the array after the loop.

Comment: any info on why the down vote? I don't have a full code sample to work with, so doing the best I can.

Comment: You gave answer to incomplete question. You didn't ask for `emit` method definition.